# Laravel Raw SQL Statements with nested where

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1

I am using two tables i.e. uploads and locations. I am trying to write a raw sql statement in laravel, but not sure whether its correct or not. I want to display all the columns of locations table where city="something" and project_id ="something".Project_id belongs to locations table.

```
$get_all_data = \DB::select('select * from locations where city = ?', [$city],'select * from uploads where project_id=?',[$getProjectId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.column, table2.column FROM table WHERE table1.city="something" AND table2.product_id="something" JOIN table2 ON table1.key=table2.key.
```

I wouldn't call this a nested where. It's just a join with multiple where clauses. Notice the caps.